# How to see the password in rhel6

Tags: linux, rhel, password

How to see the password what we are entering in RHEL6. If not how to see at least the entering password in some special characters.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you don't. Most intelligent programs deliberately mask or simply do not echo a password being entered. You can always type it in plain text in a terminal window and then use cut-and-paste to enter it, but that's defeating the purpose of masking the password as it's being entered.

Comment: Is it possible to make it like some ******** like this. So,that i can see how many characters i am entering@John

Comment: If you're writing the code, absolutely. If you're using the code someone else written, see my answer.